# what is the best design pattern for make bank statement?

Tags: design-patterns, bank

I have problem to solve and I try my best but @_@

All banks allow their customer to accessing bank statement for earlier months contain all information about all transactions withdraw,Depositing and transfer.

My question is :

what is the best design pattern to solve this problem ?

maybe i need more than one design pattern!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design patterns are no substitute for plain old OO design. Just because they're there doesn't mean they must be used. IMHO, you should use classic, SOLID OO principles to model reality and then applicable patterns may 'emerge'.

A Customer has an/many account(s) that have many transactions. A transaction can be a debit or a  credit. A transaction occurs at a point in time. I don't see the need for any particular design pattern here. A simple OO model should meet your needs.

I'm happy to be corrected...

Comment: Thanks man; this problem we get it in design pattern and my  tutor tell us solve this with suitable design pattern we have to use one or more of those pattern observer,factory,builder,singleton,decorator,composite,Adapter,Bridge,Facade, Iterator,Memento,State,

Comment: Ahh, it's one of those. You'll need to iterate over something at some point, probably transactions for a given customer, so an Iterator will help you. As to the others, I'm not sure any of them are a natural fit to the problem.

Comment: thanks David I used composite pattern and i think it's suitable enough